# Python: Create an empty dict from A to Z without J and Y

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an empty dict from A to Z without J and Y.

`my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase}`

With this, I create an empty dict with all alphabets but I want a list without J and Y. How I can make this.

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: `my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase if not in 'YJ'}` should work.

Comment: There are not enough answers using a dictionary comphrension

Answer (score 4):

You can have conditions in dict comprehension

```
my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x not in "YJ"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x not in ['J','Y']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a hard-coded string, you could use an if statement but there isn't any need to

```
my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ"}
```

Comment: really generalizable too ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands - Its actually inspired by a google interview question, whats the most efficient way to write fizzbuzz, where the answer is a hard-coded list ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
{x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x not in 'JY'}
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_dict = {x: [0] * 15 for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x not in ["J", "Y"]}`

This should do the job

Comment: Why create a list ["J", "Y"]? @Arkenys

Comment: Because the solution with a list is working maybe ? What is the purpose of providing the exact same solution as others that already answered with ```in "JY"``` ?

Comment: That solution requires a list creation which is not as optimized as "JY". Also not readable (comparing to simple string).

Comment: If you think a list is not readable, then  I won't imagine how more complicated structures appear to you tbh. It's maybe less optimized because required a list creation, but it also show that you can use a list to do the same job. Which, in other cases than just working with simple chars could be useful.